# Have a chat room where all the site moderators are contactable

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, community, chat

Currently there is no **single point of contact**, to be able to reach all the moderators. With their mutual understanding, moderators should create/rename a chat-room, which can be reached by all the users.
Since, the chatroom belongs to moderators, they can always unfreeze the room after long period of inactivity. Also they may delete the non-productive chats.

On the other side, users also responsibly should use this chat-room only for the purpose of issue-discussions, and use other chat-rooms for philosophy, chit-chatting, timepass and so on.

**Objective**: With this, many complaint based meta posts can be avoided.

Comment: More chatrooms will make the discussions more distracted and dividing.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, that's why I am suggesting to have a single point of contact; i.e. single chat room for the moderation purpose. For different purposes, there are already different chatroom. It's good not to mix moderation with the other religious discussions.

Comment: What abotu the main chatroom, that can be used for it

Comment: Flagging for moderator attention is exactly designed for when you need to directly contact the moderators. What sorts of discussions are you expecting to hold in chat that aren't better handled by the community (which *includes* the moderators) in meta?

Comment: @gold, edit wars, deletion of post/comments, rejection of flag, closure of Qn, trespassing 'be nice' policy, opinion mismatch ...

Comment: @iammilind Those all sound like exactly the sorts of things that should be discussed on meta. What makes discussing them in a dedicated chat room a more desirable solution?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44562122#44562122

Comment: As far as i have understood it has nothing to do with a particular room but with the fact that all the Mods must be "regularly" posting messages in that room.. Unless they keep doing that they are not pingable in that particular room. @iammilind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a room  called [Moderation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198/moderation).

It is active but gallery. Only some approved users can talk. Hence, it is not much of a use for contacting moderators. I propose that it should be made public. When there are troublesome discussions, it can be made gallery. There should other non mod Room Owners who can take care of chat room moderation in the absence of moderators. Good example is [Tavern on Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/) where there are many CM and employees present in the room but at the same time, there are many Room Owners who take care of room moderation.

There was a chat room named [Hinduism Ask a moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15978/hinduism-ask-a-moderator) in the past. There was very low activity and it was frozen for inactivity. (Network wide 10kers only)

The problem is not having a chat room but lack of active participation of moderators in chat rooms.

---

**Update:** It is now **[official](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/have-a-chat-room-where-all-the-site-moderators-are-contactable#comment5784_1332)** that, anyone may enter and talk in [**Moderation**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198/moderation) chatroom, for the same purpose.

Comment: I was also in favour of the `moderation` chat-room for this purpose. But there are 2 issues: (1) Only 1 Mod is pingable (2) All users may not have access. (Probably users can request access). What is your take on these?

Comment: @iammilind For few days, i didn't visit any rooms (as i was busy with some personal works) but i am free now to visit chat rooms.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, OK, that's nice. Since we cannot decide which room the Mods team choose, after the agreement within the Mod team, it will be good if either you or others, **post an answer** with the definitive link to the whichever Moderation chat room.  Mods may have discretion to give the access to all users or request based access.

Comment: @iammilind I think we can make the Moderation room public instead of creating new room, if many users want to contact mods.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Done!

Answer (score 5):

There is already a chatroom called Moderation: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198/moderation

At least 2 moderators are contactable there i.e. TheDestroyer and Pandya.

But you'll have to request for access for that room since it's a gallery.

Comment: Having access in pending in a gallery is as good as having a read only room. Not two moderators, only one moderator is available for ping.

Comment: Well I think Both are very responsible and active  unlike the 3rd one.

Comment: Heh, who is the second one you are talking about? Inactivity is inactivity.

Comment: I am talking about both " TheDestroyer and Pandya" .

Comment: Are you able to ping The Destroyer in any Moderation room? All the moderators were active in the past. Now, both of them you mentioned are pingable but in philosophical rooms but not in Moderation room. It takes only one minute to stay in the room to be pingable.

Comment: Well I am not sure why he is not pingable, but I have seen him actively doing his job. btw I am not defending him, I am just saying based on what I observed.