# What is the purpose of the Moderation chat room? Why does it remain frozen?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, moderation, chat

Why was the [Moderation chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198/moderation) created? Why does it remain frozen currently?

A few days ago a mod left a message for me in this room but there's no way to respond.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54361857#54361857

Is this now being used for 1-way communication?

**EDIT**:

A mod clarified in [an answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1904/2995) below that:

> That time our [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189) used to be active with general discussion hence [the Moderation room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50198) was created to handle the traffic and try to solve disputes.

Going forward, should issues with moderation (declined flags, post closures, etc.) be discussed in this chat room or can they be posted on the meta site as well?

There were a few occasions when a message posted in this chat room was ignored by the mods so a user may eventually end up posting about their problem on meta. So should users first try to discuss/resolve their issue in this chat room and post on meta if there was no resolution?

Comment: I suggest joining [main](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) chatroom for 2-way communication.

Comment: You may want to check [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54885401#54885401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moderation chat room was initially created to facilitate discussions regarding [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) and [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators) when we used to have lots of repeated meta posts on it.

As [known to you](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/50198?m=34156770#34156770) also from the very first day of the chat-room:

> [image]

That a time our main chat-room used to be active with general discussion and hence this room was created to handle the traffic and try to solve disputes. As the time passed eventually the room become inactive and freezes which was unfrozen sometimes as per requirement.

Until 12 May 2018. This room used to be private gallery (only allowed users can talk). On 12 May 2018, this room was made public chat-room as per the discussion [**Have a chat room where all the site moderators are contactable**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1334/277). It used to freeze sometimes due to inactivity when there was no moderation discussions and disputes and was unfrozen by moderators when required.

In August 2019 it made frozen due to some non-constructive or confusing discussion going on and recently unfrozen as mentioned by Glorfindel in his answer.

> A few days ago a mod left a message for me in this room but there's no way to respond.

Yes, you can now respond to the messages. Or anytime ping us on main chat-room in case if room found frozen.

> Going forward, should issues with moderation (declined flags, post closures, etc.) be discussed in this chat room or can they be posted on the meta site as well?

You're free to discuss on chat as well as on meta. Pinging in chat would be useful for a quick understanding or clarification of small issues while for major issues or issues concerning community, policy etc. asking on Meta is recommended especially when something needs to be documented.

> There were a few occasions when a message posted in this chat room was ignored by the mods so a user may eventually end up posting about their problem on meta. So should users first try to discuss/resolve their issue in this chat room and post on meta if there was no resolution?

You're free to post your queries on meta (make sure to search for similar already discussed problems which may answer your queries). There is no such rule that you should first try to resolve in chat but doing so (real-time discussion) would  work sometimes depending upon what you're looking for and availability of mods on chat-room.

Comment: After reading your answer, I added a couple more questions in my post.

Comment: @sv. Answer has been revised to address your queries :)

Answer (score 2):

It has been frozen because of inactivity, since it wasn't used for 14 days. See e.g. [Why do inactive chat rooms become "frozen"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208588/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

♦ moderators don't notice this, since they can post messages regardless of whether the room has been frozen or not. All Stack Exchange moderators can unfreeze rooms (I am one on other sites in the network) and I have done so now, so you can reply. As a side-effect, Feeds started to [post a string of overdue RSS messages about new Meta posts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54434586).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this is a site-specific issue. According to [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51328922#51328922) message the room was frozen by one of the mods here. I remember flagging this message a few months ago so the room can be unfrozen but it wasn't probably because another network mod who responded to my flag thought it was frozen for some specific reason.